# Is it possible to make Cloud Storage objects visible to users authenticated via application?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-iam

As it stands, my web application allows end-users to upload images to Google Cloud Storage using signed URLs which are generated on the back-end.

I'd like to also make these objects visible to these users after they've been uploaded. The simplest solution I can imagine would be to allow read access using something like `allAuthenticatedUsers` but winnowed to only apply to users who've authenticated using my application. I haven't found a way to do this, but it seems like it would be a pretty obvious solution to what must be a common problem. If it's not possible, I'm guessing it's because Google makes no distinction about *how* this user became authenticated, just that they are.

The alternative solution that comes to mind is creating IAM member accounts for users after they log in for the first time and restricting access to only those accounts, but I'd like to take the path of least resistance.

Comment: I gave you a link to get you started. As I said, if you don't know the technology, you will have work to do. I will leave the research up to you. I have deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the case you are using App Engine you can use the App Engine App Identity service. In this way your users will be able to access the data using the App Engine service account credentials. More information about configuring this can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#signing-gcp).

If this is not the case for you, creating IAM service account would be the single option I can see. You can do it programmatically using the [Identity and Access Management (IAM) API](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/). You can also create a [Google group](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/collaboration#group) and add only invited users to the group. Then, you can give the group members the role : storage.objectViewer.

Comment: I'm not using App Engine and your proposed solution is pretty much aligned with what I was figuring I'd have to do. In the meantime, I may add a proxy endpoint which creates either one-time-use GET URLs.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this [example python signed url implementation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-manually). With the following steps:

1. Construct [canonical request](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/canonical-requests) with the path to resource to sign.
2. Create a hex-encodec hash value of the above request. [You can use haslib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html).
3. Construct the string-to-sign, that includes following elments:

```
SIGNING_ALGORITHM: This should be GOOG4-RSA-SHA256.
CURRENT_DATETIME: The current date and time, in the ISO 8601 basic format YYYYMMDD'T'HHMMSS'Z'.
CREDENTIAL SCOPE: The credential scope of the request for signing the string-to-sign.
HASHED_CANONICAL_REQUEST: The hex-encoded, SHA-256 hash of the canonical request, which you created in the previous step.
```

4. Sign the string-to-sign using an RSA signature with SHA-256, [for example](https://gist.github.com/lkdocs/6519366)
5. Construct the signed URL by using the following concatenation:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/ + PATH_TO_RESOURCE + "?" + CANONICAL_QUERY_STRING + "&X-Goog-Signature=" + REQUEST_SIGNATURE
```

Please check this [python sample of implementation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-manually#python-sample).

Comment: Thanks for this answer and the links. As mentioned above, I've been considering this approach, but I'm a little wary of relying on a blocking third-party request -- in effect, _two_ blocking third-party requests -- just to display images.

Comment: You can consider allowing anonymous access to the images, so they will be visible just with this path directly: https://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET_NAME/OBJECT_NAME

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've been able to get way with when doing similar integrations in the past. Unfortunately, that's a non-starter this time around.

Comment: So I recommend implementing above scenario, as it is practically ready-made to use, and test if it meets your needs.